# Android Studio stucks on the splash screen after patching the upgrade

Tags: installation, intellij-idea, android-studio

I downloaded ***android-studio-ide-143.2443734-windows.zip***  (Android studio 2.0 )
 patch file to upgrade my current IDE (I'm using *windows 7 32 bit*).  I know that this version is multiple times faster, my computer is cheap & slow one so I was so eager to install this update, please help me.

1. I remove the all content of android studio installation
2. Then I replace with the content of the zip files

Then splash screen appeared but `being stuck` :

EDIT : Even after working sometimes the problem still happens (still get stuck even up to 1 hour) then I've to restart computer and try my luck again.

[image]

I've been waiting for about ~5 hours hoping that it will finish but it keeps stucking.

Or perhaps I applied wrong way in patching the upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, this is how I made it work:

- Uninstall all JDK and JRE
- Remove all file in "C:\Program Files\Java"
- Install the latest JDK (jdk1.8.0_66)
- Run Android Studio 2.0 Preview

On the first run Android Studio couldn't find the SDK but after indicating the correct path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66" it all worked.